# Image script injection

Tags: javascript, image, code-injection

Hey I am trying to defend my application from injecting javascripts inside images.
I am curious how does the browser appends images to the page so the script can be executed?I dont see how it can be done inside

```
<a href="image.png></a>
```

??

Answer (score 1):

Although, these old vulnerabilities have been patched in most of the modern browsers, you could try some of these attacks:

```
 <img src="javascript:alert('ALERT');">
 <img src=javascript:alert('ALERT')>
 <img src=`javascript:alert("ALERT, 'ALERT'")`>
 <img src='#' onerror=alert(1) />
```

You can find full details and more examples [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet). Also, check how can you inject in `<input>` and other tags.

**Edit**: When you inject javascript in an image's meta-data, then, it wouldn't be executed as javascript, it will be interpreted as image. PS: Regardless of any payload/javascript in an image, your browser won't evaluate it as JavaScript.

Comment: No. This is not the case. I mean injecting javascript into JPG IMAGE. Changing metadata etc.

Comment: When you inject javascript in an image's meta-data, then, it wouldn't be executed as javascript, it will be interpreted as image. PS: Regardless of any payload/javascript in an image, your browser won't evaluate it as JavaScript.(I've edited in the answer as well)

Answer (score 0):

The usual attack vectors are:

- By using a `javascript:` scheme URI for the `src` of the image (some modern browsers mitigate this by refusing to support `javascript:` scheme URIs for image sources).
- By using bad image data that triggers a buffer overflow (or other low level security vulnerability) in the underlying image processing library the browser uses to render the image.

---

From the website you link to in the comments (it would have been helpful to mention that in the question itself since it is really obscure):

That technique just creates a file which is both an image and a JavaScript program. When loaded in the context of an image, it is treated like an image. When loaded in the context of a script, it is treated like a script.

To execute the image-script as a script you would have to add `<script src="image.gif"></script>`. There's almost never a reason to let people add script elements, so just don't do that.

Comment: No. This is not the case. I mean injecting javascript into JPG IMAGE. Changing metadata etc.

Comment: Browsers don't do anything with image metadata (beyond looking at the dimensions to figure out what size it is) by default.

Comment: @repo — "For example, if you are able to put a script tag on a website but cant run the script because it only runs scripts from this website" — So it requires that you tell the browser to treat the image as a script and not as an image and is harmless when you load it as an image.